# Linux LDAP to Ldapadmin configuration issues

Tags: ldap, openldap, single-sign-on, drupal7

I'm learning how to setup and use OpenLDAP installed on an Ubuntu server.
I executed `sudo apt-get install slapd ldap-utils -y` and set my ldap domain to `test.mydomain.com`.

I can execute `ldapadd` successfully to add people via that domain.

So, I'm trying to use [Ldapadmin](http://www.ldapadmin.org/) to inspect the sample data in my sample LDAP server. My LDAP host is required and I provide the following, using port #**389**:

> `ldap://*.*.*.*/test.mydomain.com`
>   (*the asterics represent my ip address*)

When the host is tested, I get an **LADP Error: server down!** message.

Getting it to work on Ldapadmin is the first step to using the same configuration on my Drupal website to enable Single-Sign-on.

Can anyone help, please?

**UPDATE**

@Brian Showalter:

In */etc/phpldapadmin/config.php* I re-set the following:

> $servers->setValue('server','host','');
>
> $servers->setValue('server','base',array('dc=ldaptest,dc=com'));

So, it's now **ldaptest.com** instead of **test.mydomain.com**. I also executed `dpkg-reconfigure slapd` to amend the domain.

However I'm a bit confused about your statement "`... use ldap://<server IP or hostname> as the LDAP URI...`". Is that to be set in **Ldapadmin** or to replace the value of server-host as in the server setting above?

I apologise if my question(s) are basic. I just learning this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your LDAP domain should probably just be `mydomain.com`, not `test.mydomain.com`. This is also known as the base name in `dc=mydomain,dc=com` format. You might want to do a `dpkg-reconfigure slapd` to reconfigure your OpenLDAP installation accordingly.

Then, use `ldap://<server IP or hostname>` as the LDAP URI (don't include the domain on the end), and set Ldapadmin to use `dc=mydomain,dc=com` as the base.  You may also need to specify a bind DN (which looks something like `cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com`) and a bind password in order to fully connect to your server.

Comment: Hi Brian. Thanks for your response. I posted an update to my question

Comment: You mention Ldapadmin and phpldapadmin, which are two different LDAP clients. In the phpldapadmin config, you have the right value for the base, but the host value should be set to either the hostname or the IP address of your LDAP server (do not prefix this with "ldap://").